# Problem with Assigning value to specific pandas cell in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to assign a flag type indicator to my dataframe to identify special rows.
I tried to assign value via the index.
When I process the below code; I expect the first row to be No but my output is Yes. Why is this not working? Seems to be straightforward code.

```
loDf['indi']="Yes"
loDf.indi[0]="No"

print(loDf.indi[0])

#Prints Yes instead of No
```

Comment: Use `loc` like `loDf.loc[0, 'indi']="No"`

Comment: thanks, it worked. but curios why my code didnt work